# How to use apply family to

Tags: r, apply, covariance, data-manipulation, mapply

This may be an apply question / a data management question / a combination of those. I am relatively new to R, and am adjusting extensively to how to manage data in R vs. Stata (as an example). I've read extensively, but have not found a good example of how to (1) extract vectors from a dataframe by group;  (2) apply a function pairwise against all combinations of those vectors; and (3) output the results as a matrix, so I am asking you all how to do so. I simplified all variable names / data in the example below:

I have a dataframe df structured as follows:

```
id score1 score2 extravar1 extravar2 .....
1     10      9        a   1.4345124      
1      9      7        b   1.1133529
1      5      5        c   -0.1712851
2      4      4        d   -0.4924446
2      3      2     junk   -0.8136040
2      6      6     junk   0.14987444
3      5      6     junk   0.14331245
etc
```

I need to create a covariance matrix of ID score1 subsets and ID score2 subsets. In other words, I would like to run the following calculations for both score1 and score2:

```
cov(vector of df$score1 for id 1 only,df$score1 for id 1 only) 
cov(vector of df$score1 for id 1 only,df$score1 for id 2 only)
cov(vector of df$score1 for id 1 only,df$score1 for id 3 only)
.
.
.
cov(vector of df$score1 for id 1 only,df$score1 for id 288 only)
cov(vector of df$score1 for id 1 only,df$score1 for id 289 only)
cov(vector of df$score1 for id 2 only,df$score1 for id 1 only) 
cov(vector of df$score1 for id 2 only,df$score1 for id 2 only)
.
.
.
cov(vector of df$score1 for id 289 only,df$score1 for id 288 only)
cov(vector of df$score1 for id 289 only,df$score1 for id 289 only)
```

and I would like the data to output into two (one fore score1, one for score2) lists, dataframes, or matrices that looks like (where s1-1 is score1 vector for id=1):

```
         1               2               3       ...    288           289
1  cov(s1-1,s1-1)  cov(s1-1,s1-2) cov(s1-1,s1-3)   cov(s1-1,s1-288)   cov(s1-1,s1-289)
2  cov(s1-2,s1-1)  cov(s1-2,s1-2) cov(s1-2,s1-3)   cov(s1-2,s1-288)   cov(s1-2,s1-289)
3  cov(s1-3,s1-1)  cov(s1-3,s1-2) cov(s1-3,s1-3)   cov(s1-3,s1-288)   cov(s1-3,s1-289)
.
.
.
288 cov(s1-288,s1-1)  cov(s1-288,s1-2) cov(s1-288,s1-3) cov(s1-288,s1-288) cov(s1-288,s1-289)
289 cov(s1-289,s1-1)  cov(s1-289,s1-2) cov(s1-289,s1-3) cov(s1-289,s1-288) cov(s1-289,s1-289)
```

My problem is that I am running into issues (1) manipulating the data so that it is in the right format for such an analysis and (2) deciding which of the apply functions would be most appropriate to use (mapply maybe?). Currently, I am using split to separate the data into groups, but am lost how to manipulate it from there:

```
df.scores <- df[,c("id","score1","score2")]
databy.id <- split(df.scores,df.scores$id)
```

Which yields a list I am not 100% clear on how to manipulate in apply. head(databy.id) looks roughly like this:

```
$`1`
           id score1      score2 
1           1     10           9 
2           1      9           7 
3           1      5           5 
4           1      4           4 
5           1      3           2 
...

$`2`
           id score1      score2 
1           2      8           3 
2           2      9           2 
3           2     10           1 
4           2      9           3 
5           2      4           9 
...

$`3`
           id score1      score2 
1           3      8           7 
2           3      3           4 
3           3      2           3 
4           3      4           6 
5           3      6           1 
...
```

I can (and have) solved this with loops, but would prefer not to, as I next need to repeatedly randomize scores and simulate/store many such matrices (which is taking excessively long via loops). Should I be using ddply, mapply or some other functions? Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I learned the cov function takes matrices. I've figure out how to reform all of the ID vectors of scores into a matrix using a loop, and am calculating the covariance matrix this way. However, this is an inelegant solution, and I am pretty sure there is a better way to initialize the data frame I am using (where ids is a vector of all of the ids:

```
vectors.score1 <- data.frame("1"=databy.id[[1]]$score1)
for (j in 2:length(ids)) {
  vectors.score1[,toString(ids[j])] <- databy.id[[j]]$score1  
}
covariances <- cov(vectors.score1,vectors.score1)
colnames(covariances) <- ids
```

I would be interesting in a more elegant solution to reshape the data, should someone have it

Edit: Fixed naming of variable Impact ==> score1

Comment: This does not seem to address your question. There is no mention of "Impact" in the question.